# I have many friends,who all or all of whom are students

Tags: who

which is correct "I have many friends,who all are University students" or "I have many friends,all of whom are University students"?

Comment: @aparente001 is correct: "who all are" is not right. I would always say "who are all" rather than "all of whom"; perhaps this is because I am British.

Comment: @TonyK - I wonder what happened to my comment?  I don't recall writing anything that could have been flagged for removal.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, but the second is much more frequently used. I enter ", who all" into COCA https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/, and it returns 248 results. 1536 example sentences with ", all of whom" are found in the corpus.

Comment: I think this is a regional thing. As a Brit, I prefer "I have many friends, who are all university students" by a large margin.

Comment: Yes, if I had to guess I'd say the one with "all of whom" (while meaning the same thing) is more formal.